# What conic curve is the graph of y=sin(x) from 0 to pi?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Certainly is not a circle; it looks like an ellipse but I don't think it is.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, it's called a [sinusoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave). It's *not* a conic.

Comment: @Mielu, generally questions here are closed only if they are off topic or ill posed. However, if an answer to your question suits you, you can accept it by clicking the check mark to the left. This will let others know that you have received a satisfactory answer.